# Ec2 instance not reachable after ./gradlew assemble

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, gradle, amazon-ec2

The problem :
I have a react application in my ec2 instance(ubuntu). I'm trying to execute this command but it gets stuck while trying to execute "npm run build"

```
./gradlew :webapp:assemble
```

Faulty Process :
When I do this, some process goes on succesfully, until it calls `npm run build`. After that terminal freezes as it is and does not give any error messages until I get an ssh connection time out error. When I try to reconnect to instance with ssh, instance doesn't respond in any way.

What I checked/tried :
I've tried to do same operation with same application in my own pc and there isn't any problem. I also tried to run `npm run build` in ec2 without using gradle and its also working fine so I don't think there is any problem about my react application.

How can I troubleshoot this and learn what's causing instance to stuck in a not reachable state ? For example, is there a way to learn if this is caused by too high CPU usage ?

Comment: You can see an instance's cpu usage on the EC2 console.  Does the instance have a working outgoing Internet connection, i.e. there is an Internet Gateway configured for the subnet it's in, and security groups/network acls are properly configured to allow outgoing traffic?

Comment: Along with cpu, check the ram as well. Maybe run a custom script which sends you ram info. What is the ec2 instance type and your own pc config?

Comment: @jingx yes server has those. I am able to check cpu usage but I don't know if its critical or not

Comment: @Riz I will check RAM too thanks. I tried in a ubuntu VM with same memory etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Riz 's comment I realized that there is a problem caused by insufficient ram. I Solved it by switching to another machine with more RAM